# Spark - jdbc read all happens on driver?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have spark reading from Jdbc source (oracle) I specify lowerbound,upperbound,numpartitions,partitioncolumn but looking at web ui all the read is happening on driver not workers,executors. Is that expected?

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#manage-parallelism

Comment: In the Spark UI, you can see that the numPartitions dictate the number of tasks that are launched. Each task is spread across the executors, which can increase the parallelism of the reads and writes through the JDBC interface. See the Spark SQL programming guide for other parameters, such as fetchsize, that can help with performance.

Comment: running app how?

Comment: spark-submit client mode, standalone scheduler, master spark://host:7077, there are workers registered with the master

Answer (score 0):

In Spark framework, in general whatever code you write within a transformation such as map, flatMap etc. will be executed on the executor. To invoke a transformation you need a RDD which is created using the dataset that you are trying to compute on. To materialize the RDD you need to invoke an action so that transformations are applied to the data.

I believe in your case, you have written a spark application that reads jdbc data. If that is the case it will all be executed on Driver and not executor.

If you haven not already, try creating a Dataframe using [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,columnName:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) API.

Comment: I read into df but only transform stage are running on executors. The read stage of 50million rows from oracle is all happening on driver :-(

Comment: it might be helpful if you could post some of your code and show us what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't have on hand but to start with 2 lines. Val df= jdbc.read.xxxx; df.write.parquet

Comment: In the Spark UI, you can see that the numPartitions dictate the number of tasks that are launched. Each task is spread across the executors, which can increase the parallelism of the reads and writes through the JDBC interface. See the Spark SQL programming guide for other parameters, such as fetchsize, that can help with performance.

Not convinced your answer is correct.